# select the results in a horizontal format as below in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm having a table like this.

A Seller table like this:

[image: A Seller table like this]

Code for the same table is:

```
create table sellers (seller_id int, country varchar(30), Month varchar(30), Sales int);'''

insert into sellers values 
(1, 'I', 'January', 10000),
(1, 'I', 'Februray', 60000),
(1, 'I', 'March', 80000),
(2, 'In', 'january', 20000), 
(2, 'In', 'February', 10000),
(2, 'In', 'March', 10000), 
(3, 'Ind', 'january', 50000),
(3, 'Ind', 'March', 20000),
(3, 'Ind', 'February', 10000)
;
```

I'd like to get the result in the below format

Result format like this:

[image: Result format like this]

I tried an SQL code like this and unable to retrieve the result:

```
select seller_id, 
(select sales where month = 'January') as Jan_sales, 
(select sales where month = 'February') as Feb_sales, 
(select sales where month = 'March') as Mar_sales
from sellers group by seller_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a fake aggregation function

```
select country
  , max(if(month = 'January', sales, 0) Jan_sales
  , max(if(month = 'February', sales, 0) Feb_sales
  , max(if(month = 'March', sales, 0) Mar_sales
from sellers
group by country
```